# F# type test pattern matching: decomposing tuple objects

Tags: f#, tuples, pattern-matching, decomposition

Just curious why I can't do this:

```
let myFn (data : obj) =
    match data with
    | :? (string * string) as (s1, s2) -> sprintf "(%s, %s)" s1 s2 |> Some
    | :? (string * string * int) as (s1, s2, i) -> sprintf "(%s, %s, %d)" s1 s2 i |> Some
    | _ -> None
```

How come?

Comment: That would be nice. Shame it's not supported.

Comment: While this could be suggested in https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions , I think it's a bad idea as it would encourage people to write code like this. This code should be avoided because it requires use of `obj` and type matching. F# should be used in a type-safe way, and use of `obj` and downcasting detracts from that.

Answer (score 2):

See [F# spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf), section 7.3 "As patterns"

*An as pattern is of the form `pat as ident`*

Which means you need to use an identifier after `as`:

```
let myFn (data : obj) =
    match data with
    | :? (string * string)       as s1s2  -> let (s1, s2)    = s1s2  in sprintf "(%s, %s)" s1 s2 |> Some
    | :? (string * string * int) as s1s2i -> let (s1, s2, i) = s1s2i in sprintf "(%s, %s, %i)" s1 s2 i |> Some
    | _ -> None
```

Comment: I know what the spec says.  I was looking for a more technical explanation as to why deconstruction of a tuple after "as" isn't supported -- especially since most users would intuit this of the language.

Comment: There's no technical limitation, other than the feature is not implemented. There are other places where de-construction is not supported, like in the "this" parameter of members, which is a place where you frequently want to deconstruct. All this can be added to the language after submitting a proposal, and getting approval for it.